# Nginx HTTPS (443) config ignored and HTTP (80) used instead

Tags: nginx, ssl, server

I was trying to redirect non secure (domain.com and [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)) to secure version and I was getting a "too many redirects" error.

So, I decided to simplify the config to test and try to find out the error.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 302 https://www.google.com;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/cert.key;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    
    return 302 https://www.amazon.com;
}
```

If I am not wrong, when I visit *http://example.com/* or *http://www.example.com/*, I should be redirected to https://www.google.com

And I if I visit *https://example.com/* or *https://www.example.com/*, I should be redirected to https://www.amazon.com

But, any case, I am always redirected to https://www.google.com. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser might be **caching** the redirects.
Try using Incognito windows for both the test cases. Your config file seems to be fine.

For your domain.com, you can have following configuration:

```
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 443;

  root /var/www/html;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```